# Google Play Billing v5 - List all Available Products

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

Is there a way to list all available products using Play Billing v5?

Every implementation I've seen you need to provide the product ID, and I don't have a backend to keep track of these IDs and I don't want to hardcode them in the app, so there must be a way to retrieve a list of all of the product IDs associated with an app, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `I don't have a backend to keep track of these IDs`

You don't need to keep track of product ids, Google keeps them for you, before you can use the product id, you should first create it in Google Play Developer Console
[image]

2. `and I don't want to hardcode them in the app`
   You must do this, since most of the google billing api need product id to fetch product/purchase details.

Follow Google Play billing integration documents: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate